# How do I enter a house sale into my accounting package?

Tags: accounting, home-ownership, double-entry

We sold our house and purchased a new one. The money from the sale went into our lawyer's trust account, and then was passed onto the vendor that sold us the new house.

In my accounting package, I have a Sales Invoice and a Purchases Invoice, and I need to credit one against the other.

Where do I code those transactions that didn't go through my bank account?

Should I just create a new account code, i.e. Lawyer's Trust Account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I just create a new account code, i.e. Lawyer's Trust Account?

Yes, you should. I have a generic "escrow" account just for that.